# Laravel: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel

I tried to make a social networking site type of project and tried to delete a post when the user is logged in, and he will only be allowed to delete his posts, and can only like and dislike other's posts. 
But, when I tried to delete it: it shows error -

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

And, before this editing. when anyone was able to delete anyone's post, with the code:

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id){

    $post = Post::where('user_id',$post_id)->first();

    if (Auth::user() != $post->user) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    if ($post != null) {
        $post->delete();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
    }

    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Wrong ID!!']);
}
```

It only shows: "Wrong ID!!" every time and do not delete the post.

The columns of users table: id, email, password
The columns of posts table: id, created_at,updated_at,body,user_id

And, user_id of posts table links with the id of users table.

Added dd(Auth::user(), $post):

```
User {#183 ▼
#connection: null
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
#perPage: 15
+incrementing: true
+timestamps: true
#attributes: array:7 [▶]
#original: array:7 [▶]
#relations: []
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#appends: []
#fillable: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#casts: []
#touches: []
#observables: []
#with: []
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
null
```

**What is wrong here?**

Part of code containing delete button: from dashboard.blade.php:

```
<div class="interaction">
                <a href="#">Like</a> |
                <a href="#">Dislike</a> 
                @if(Auth::user() == $post->user)
                |
                <a href="#">Edit</a> |
                <a href="{{route('post.delete',['post_id=>$post->id'])}}">Delete</a> 
                @endif
            </div>
```

Comment: Please put this before the first `if` and show us what output is  `dd(Auth::user(), $post);`

Comment: @Alexey Mezenin - Did it, Please check now.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted the asnwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get data from `null`, so it causes the error. Just add `$post != null` to the first `if` and it will work as you expect:

```
public function getDeletePost($post_id){

    $post = Post::where('user_id',$post_id)->first();

    if ($post != null && Auth::user() != $post->user) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    if ($post != null) {
        $post->delete();
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Successfully deleted!!']);
    }

    return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message'=> 'Wrong ID!!']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It's not showing that error now. But it is causing the same problem i mentioned in my question. It is saying "Wrong id!!", what is causing this problem?

Comment: It means you have no `Post` with `user_id = $post_id` in the table. Maybe you want to search for `'id' == $post_id` instead of `'user_id' == $post_id`?

Comment: I tried using $id instead of $user_id, but shows same error

Comment: Please show your table structure and `dd($post_id);` output then I'll be able to help you with it.

Comment: dd($post_id): output -"post_id=>$post->id"

Comment: It should give you an integer

Comment: Yes, but it's not giving me any integer value.

Comment: If you want help, you should show part of Blade template which creates a delete link or delete button and also table structure.

Comment: Okay, I added the code. please check and thank you :)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is in your `route()`, try this `route('post.delete', $post->id)`. Also, make sure your route is `GET` and looks similar to this `Route::get('delete/{post_id}', ['as' => 'post.delete', 'uses' =>  'SomeController@getDeletePost'])`

Comment: Did it, thank you .Now, it's just not showing the "Wrong Id" message, but still not doing anything.

Comment: Well, you should go and see if it passes correct ID with `dd($post_id)`, if not, you should look into your link code and `route::get()` structure.

Comment: Okay, I'll check that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `firstOrFail()` instead of using `first()` as:

```
$post = Post::where('user_id',$post_id)->firstOrFail();
```

If you use `firstOrFail()` then it will confirm that your `$post` object is a model object, not a `null`.

The `firstOrFail()` methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown. So you have to never require a `if` check.

Comment: but, I am checking it by using the if statement. So, I need to check it two times? or I should just remove the if statement

Comment: In your first `if` statement you are using, `$post->user`. So this may be causing the problem.

Comment: JFI - Why you are querying on `user_id`  column with variable name `$paost_id`. Isn't it should be as `Post::where('id',$post_id)`.

Comment: Yes, i thought so. Tried it. but, this also shows same error.

Comment: Then you have to make sure that you have `Post` in the table with `id` of `$post_id`. I can see only this can be the possible issue. Or you can check your SQL query using `toSql()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Edited

```
 public function getDeletePost($post_id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($post_id);
        if ($post) {
            if (auth()->user()->id != $post->user_id) {
                return redirect()->back();
            }
            $post->delete();
            return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'Successfully deleted!!']);
        }
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'Wrong ID!!']);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you.Tried it, but shows same error:Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: can you please try `dd($post)` and see if there is a row with that post id and also check database for cross reference?

Comment: @shoieb0101-Did it, please check my question again. It shows null.

Comment: @Learning_to_solve_problems can you please check if the `$post_id` you are passing to the `method` exists in the `posts` table?

Comment: No, It contains column id. Tried with it too. But, shows same error. I'll check it again. Thank you :)